# gmail username syntax method for spam prevention

Tags: gmail, spam-prevention, mailing-list

i'm very aware that this is probably not a stackoverflow question, but i figure someone here might know the answer...

a few months back i was sent an image detailing a neat method for spam prevention using a little known feature of gmail..

basically you can use a specific syntax in your email address when you give it out to include some kind of identifier within the email address so you can later distinguish which version of your email address was distributed/crawled to create spam and then, if you want, create filters based on this identifier.

something along the lines of `username|identifier@gmail.com` which will still beforewarded to `username@gmail.com` except `|` is not the correct token and i can't find the doco where i found this information or remember what the correct special character is.

so if anyone knows about the feature i'm describing, i'd love to find out how to get it to work!

thanks, and sorry for the non-programming question.

p.

Comment: It was a `+`. And this question is definitely off topic.

Comment: for a good time, call http://webapps.stackechange.com

Comment: @msw you missed the `x` in exchange -- webapps.stackexchange.com

Comment: Yeah, it's a `+` and I make use of it -- and tons of email "validator"   regexes (found all over including here on SO) will reject it because of the plus.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `+` sign instead of the `|`